# Use standard jsp/servlet inside struts app

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts

is it possible to embed a "standard" jsp and its associated servlet in a struts 1.X app ? (It uses no action form nor bean). If so, is there any special tweak needed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly OK to use both.

You will just have to map the servlet in web.xml.